# Plotting vectors with missing values in time series

Tags: r, vector, time-series

I am trying to plot this table into parallel lines where y axis range is -50 to 150 and x axis is the vector "Days". Each vector (X1 to X8) has a lot of missing values, so I just want to plot existing values and connect them (for each vector) with lines.

This is the command I use to try to plot the data

```
 plot(dataframe,plot.type="single",ylim=c(-50,150))
```

And this is the dataframe I am trying to plot

```
     Days  X1  X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1     600 -15 -18 NA 14 NA NA NA NA
2     620  NA  NA NA NA NA NA NA 21
3     660   0  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
4     700  NA   8 NA NA NA NA NA 33
5     760  NA  NA NA  8 NA NA NA NA
6     780   0  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
7     800  NA  11 NA NA 65 NA NA NA
8     820  NA  NA NA NA NA NA NA 29
9     840  NA  NA NA NA 85 NA NA NA
10    880  NA  NA NA  5 75 NA NA NA
11    900  NA  NA NA NA NA NA 10 NA
12    920  NA  NA 12 NA NA NA NA 57
13    940  NA  22 NA NA NA NA NA NA
14    960  NA  NA 12 NA NA NA NA NA
15   1000  NA  NA 14 NA NA NA NA NA
16   1060  NA  NA 14 NA NA NA NA NA
17   1120  NA  NA 11 NA NA NA NA NA
```

But all I get is a nearly blank window.

This would be a good example of what kind of plot I am trying to get:
http://ajpheart.physiology.org/content/ajpheart/284/5/H1585/F4.large.jpg

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
matplot(dat[1],dat[-1],type="n")
Map(function(x,y) lines(x[!is.na(y)],y[!is.na(y)]),dat[1],dat[-1])
```

Result:

[image]

`matplot` essentially sets up the boundary of the plot area, and then the `Map` call plots each line in turn, removing the `NA` values.

So that you can reproduce the results, this is the `dat` dataset:

```
dat <- data.frame(Days = c(600L, 620L, 660L, 700L, 760L, 780L, 800L, 820L, 840L, 880L, 900L, 920L, 940L, 960L, 1000L, 1060L, 1120L
), X1 = c(-15L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X2 = c(-18L, NA, NA, 8L, NA, NA, 11L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 22L, NA, NA, NA, NA), X3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12L, NA, 12L, 14L, 14L, 11L), X4 = c(14L, 
NA, NA, NA, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65L, NA, 85L, 75L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 10L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X8 = c(NA, 21L, NA, 33L, NA, NA, NA, 29L, NA, NA, NA, 57L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the concept, but I am not quite sure what dat[1] and dat[-1] shuold be. This is how I did it and I still get a blank screen:

    matplot(Days,X1,type="n")
    Map(function(x,y) lines(x[!is.na(y)],y[!is.na(y)]),Days,X1)

Thanks again.

Comment: @Oposum - `dat[1]` is the first column of your dataset, which could be substituted with `dat["Days"]` - `dat[-1]` is every column of your dataset except the first "Days" column (negative of the 1st column = -1 as an index).

Comment: is "dat" a function? when I am trying the line in R, I get the message: Error in as.matrix(x) : object 'dat' not found

Comment: @Oposum - `dat` is just the name I used for what you are calling `dataframe` in your code. It's a `data.frame` object, containing your data. Try `dataframe[1]` and `dataframe[-1]` to see the results using your own code.

Comment: @Oposum - i've added the code to import `dat` to the answer so you can at least have a full complete bit example to test.

Comment: how can I add text label (like letters A,B,C,etc..) to the left from each line? (So total of 8 labels A-H).